# Different layout in Android Studio between preview and emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, layout, emulation

Why do I have two different layout results in the preview and in the emulator of the same phone? I create some AVDs to emulate the Samsung phones, but their previews and AVDs don't correspond..

Here's my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="ag.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/sfondo"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/tronco1"
                android:layout_marginTop="-250dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
                android:src="@drawable/play_h"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="#00ffffff"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton7"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton7"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton7" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
                android:src="@drawable/score_h"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="#00ffffff"
                android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton8"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton8"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton8"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
                android:src="@drawable/options_h"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="#00ffffff"
                android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton11"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton11"
                android:src="@drawable/removeads"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="#00ffffff"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="400dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/titolo"
                android:layout_marginTop="-10dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Only the ImageButtons are positioned differently, wile the imageViews are where they are supposed to be

Can you help me?

Comment: No we can't help you...Not without your layout files..

Comment: In your layout editor, from where you choose the device for preview - select "Preview All Screens" from there. The layout appears this way because your layout isn't scaling properly along with change in screen height.

Comment: There's a problem: I've added plenty of Samsung screens in the avd, which I can also see singularly in the preview, but when I select "Preview All Screens" it only shows me the previous screens, the one of default, not the one I've added. Why?
Also, in the preview mode I've checked every single Samsung device for the layout, and it is ok in all of them. In the preview mode my layout is ok in the Samsung Galaxy S5, let's say, but when I run my app on the AVD of that phone, the layout of only my ImageButtons is different..how is it possible?

Comment: Might depend on the API version (in layout editor) as 'ActionBar/Status Bar' gets added...

Comment: In the preview mode there's no action bar but there's the status bar, while in the AVD there is none of them. How can I delete the status bar in the preview? 
Anyway I've just found out that in my layout-normal this issue doesn't occur, while it does in the layout-large

Comment: And now I have both the AVD and the Preview at API 22, so that's not the problem..any suggestion on how I could solve it?

Comment: Not sure...I personally avoid using multiple resource files for a single screen. I try to design single layout that scales properly in all screen sizes...but, thats just me...

Comment: Well I may need to do the same..could you please tell me how to do it? But do you mean designing a screen for every device?

Comment: No...just one file and I make sure they appear fine in most of the device. There are many options in your case. For one you can use the @dimen resources for your imageButton dimentions

Answer (score 0):

The preview is less reliable than the AVD . You have to base yourself on your emulator display to verify that your view is displayed correctly.

It is preferable to obtain a perfect simulation of the poster of your application will emulate that on a real device.

Comment: I have an activity_main - large and on - normal. The normal one is the same on both the AVD and the preview, while the large one is not. Do you suggest me to always try the large one on a physical device?